# OCaml: assert with the message

Tags: ocaml

Another question again :P I'm not too sure whether I should post it here or on the OCaml mailing list, but I try SO first.

I like assert statements. However, I find the error messages close to useless without an additional message (assertion violation at line XXX --- well great, but what actually went wrong?). 
I think the good example of an assertion is a pythonic `assert x > 0, "X must be greater than zero for the algorithm X to work"` and a bad example is C-like `assert(x>0)`.

I was quite disappointed to learn that there is no way to attach an error message to an assertion in OCaml =(
My options are:

- Write a custom function, say `vassert` => but I won't get the magic line numbers which are only possible with the `assert` keyword
- Use `failwith`, but it is considerably more verbose, and I think suffers from the same problem as a custom function.
- Use functions from `OUnit`, but I don't want to introduce unneeded dependency.

Does anyone else have the same problem? What do people use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit tedious but works fine:

```
 assert (if not cond then print_endline "your message"; cond)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the simpler way to dot that is to compile with the -g option and then add OCAMLRUNPARAM=b to the environment.
This way you can write your own vassert, and you will get the whole stack trace that produced the call.

Of course, this is a result of my personal workflow were I consider assert as a debugging only tool that should never get seen by the final user.

Comment: A good point, but I believe it is beneficial to avoid the `utils` module with functions like that, as it often creates more problem than it solves (moving between projects/keeping it up to date/etc etc).
So a built-in construct or a library is usually a more preferable solution.